# www + subdomain URL with wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I have been developing this website in the following URL [mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my](http://mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my) which is based on Wordpress, however, somehow they want their website to be able to accessed either by the mentioned URL and  **www.mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my** (with www.) which is quite bizarre to me as I have no idea if that's possible to do so.

I have been struggling trying to get this issue solved but I never seen anyone trying to access their website using that structure. Has anyone ever faced this issue before? How did you solve it?

Ps. The website is hosted on windows server.

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify the .htaccess file on your server. So that your server will understand the upcoming request with www (`www.mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my`) and will redirect to  non www url `mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my`. Ultimately what is happening is, Every request on the URL will be redirected to `mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my` automatically. So you will be able to access your website with

use the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this will help.

EDITED :

Like you said you are using a windows server. So as you already know that you have to change web.config file.try useing the following code.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/{R:1}"></action>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com$" negate="true"></add>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

changed domain with your domain name. 
Hope it will work for subdomain aswell.

Comment: Thnank you so much. However, I forgot to mention that website is hosted on Windows server. Is that possible to convert this to web.config? Thank you

Comment: Edited my answer for web.config related changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit web.config file on your server to make desired changes in your wordpress. Place following code in your web.config file.

```
    <rewrite>
         <rules>
             <rule name="Redirect to non-www" topProcessing="true">             
        <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
                 <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/{R:1}"></action> 
                <conditions> 
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com$" negate="true"></add>
                 </conditions>  
           </rule>     
    </rules> 
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code in your .htaccess

please change your domain instead of example.com.com

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: another way is go through database and change all the urls

Comment: With this way, can people still access with mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my or just www.mytourismdata.tourism.gov.my?

Comment: even you will try to access without www it will change to www.example.com

Comment: hope this one help you..   go ahead